# What does the word 'collect' mean here in the sentence?

Tags: meaning, sentence

> Good afternoon,
>
> With regards to your request we would like to inform you that Europcar staff will collect the vehicle at requested hour.
>
> An extra cost of 20,000€+vat will apply.
>
> We remain at your disposal.
>
> With kind regards,

I thought that the word 'collect' here means 'to prepare' according to the sentence, but the teacher said the word here literally means 'to gather something', what does the word mean. Is it possible that it means the staff collect the cars for the customers to use at the requested point, they once prepared the cars and left them for use?

Comment: I mean the staff would prepare the cars for the customers to use at he requested point and time ,not pick up the used vehicle which the customers leave

Comment: Do not post text as graphics. It cannot be indexed and discriminates against people with visual problems. Transcribe it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your expectation of "to prepare" and that you think it might mean "to collect the car for the customer to use", I would agree.

**collect** in this case probably means "take from where it is located and bring to the store/office/dealership."

If you  were already in possession of the car and received this email, I would think they mean **collect from you.**

However if you are not in possession of the car, then I think it could mean **collect from some location and bring to the store-front**

That "some location" is probably an off-site parking lot, another rental location, or a parking lot behind the building.